# Merging Objects in Javascript for Infinite Loading Ajax Plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, object, merge

I am trying to implement infinite scrolling. An ajax request returns an object that includes 10 threads. This ajax request is called every time the user scrolls to the bottom. What I am looking for is a way to merge these objects together.

One object looks like this:

```
Article: Object
    page: 1
    last_page: 20
    data: Array[10]
        0: Object
        1: Object
        2: Object
```

Inside of the data array objects are arrays and objects again... So my problem here really is that we're speaking of a quite large object containing a variety of objects and arrays. Any idea how I could manage to do this?

Thank you! <3

Comment: It's not really clear what you are actually trying to achieve. Why wouldn't you be able to just merge all the `data` arrays?

Comment: I tried to do that with "concat", but it didn't work because it contains objects as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To add an array to another you could use the following code:

```
// `b` onto `a`:
a.push.apply( a, b );
```

More information on the best way of merging/combining arrays may be found at [this link](https://davidwalsh.name/combining-js-arrays).

In your case it would seem you keep one big pile of data (in the end). That would mean you would push the new article data on top of the pile. Since you know that this pile will be the biggest, it would give a good performance if you used this:

```
var articlePile = article.data;
// For every new article push the data onto the pile
articlePile.push.apply( articlePile, article2.data );
```

Comment: Thank you very much, it finally works! :) However, I'm not quite sure how your second example delivers better performance?

Comment: This is better performance, since you are pushing the smaller array (the new `article.data`) onto a bigger getting array. Suppose you run the ajax code 10 times. In this case it will be faster to push the 10 new items onto the array with 90 items than it would be to push 90 items onto an array with 10 items.

Comment: So you mean it's better to do

    articlePile.push.apply( articlePile, article2.data );

than

    article2.data.push.apply( article2.data, articlePile ); ?

I'm wondering how Facebook is doing it. I don't know if there is an end to their timeline?

Comment: @Hillcow Yes that's what I meant, not sure how Facebook does it. But just a friendly reminder: if you're not going to do anything with the data except show it on the page, you don't necessarily need to keep all the data in an array. You might as well just process the new data (outputting it to the screen) and not add it to a gigantic pile of data. Of course this depends on what you're planning to do with the data.

Comment: Oh, that's actually a pretty good and easy idea I did not have at all haha